# Dom and xpath php

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Hopefully should be a simple question for someone that has done it before!

I have a list of old web documents in table format with lots of depart and arrival time details in it. What I have managed so far is to create a PHP script that parses the XHTML doc and gets depart and arrival times and correspondance.

An example of the document format:

```
<table borderColor="#ffffff" cellSpacing="3" cellPadding="0" width="550" border="0" align="center">

                    <tr align="left">
                        <td colSpan="5">Relation
                        <span class="ttr-orange3">
                        <span id="ctl00_ctl19_g_1f57e500_cfb9_4f21_8d34_37ed46a2c243_ctl00_rptHoraire_ctl00_lblRelationGare">BERRECHID - BENGUERIR</span></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr align="center">
                        <td width="90" bgColor="#e2e2e2" height="26">Départ</td>
                        <td width="90" bgColor="#e2e2e2">Arrivée</td>
                        <td width="115" bgColor="#f0e9d9">Correspondance</td>
                        <td width="115" bgColor="#f0e9d9">Service à bord</td>
                        <td width="70" bgColor="#f0e9d9">Gamme</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr align="center" bgcolor="#F7F2E9" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='#F3EBDD';"
                        onmouseout="style.backgroundColor='#F7F2E9';">
                        <td height="20" bgcolor="#F4F4F4" width="90">05h21mn</td>
                        <td bgcolor="#F4F4F4" width="90">06h58mn</td>
                        <td width="115">-</td>
                        <td width="115"><img src='/Style%20Library/Images/CustomImages/pictos/bol.gif' width="15" height="13"></td>
                        <td width="70"><img src='/Style%20Library/Images/CustomImages/pictos/TRAIN_RAPIDE.gif' width="15" height="13"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr align="center" bgcolor="#F7F2E9" onmouseover="style.backgroundColor='#F3EBDD';"
                        onmouseout="style.backgroundColor='#F7F2E9';">
                        <td height="20" bgcolor="#F4F4F4" width="90">07h21mn</td>
                        <td bgcolor="#F4F4F4" width="90">08h56mn</td>
                        <td width="115">-</td>
                        <td width="115"><img src='/Style%20Library/Images/CustomImages/pictos/bol.gif' width="15" height="13"></td>
                        <td width="70"><img src='/Style%20Library/Images/CustomImages/pictos/TRAIN_RAPIDE.gif' width="15" height="13"></td>
                    </tr>
</table>
```

What I need to do is parse all of these [depart,arrivee,correspondace] details into an array. I have managed the basics with this so far:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
@$document->loadHtml( $content );
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$nodes = $xpath->query('//table[@width="580"]/tr');
$data = array();
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
   //Any help would be great!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath expression definitely does not correspond to the HTML code you presented.
I guess you only want the real timetable and from that only the first 3 columns.
Assuming the HTML structure stays similar to the one above, the first step would be to change your XPath so it only matches those tr blocks that have a bgcolor property.

```
$nodes = $xpath->query('//table[@width="550"]/tr[@bgcolor]');
```

Next you need to run through the td elements contained in the tr.

```
foreach ($nodes as $node)
{
    foreach($node->childNodes as $childNode)
    {
        // --- process the td elements ---
    }
}
```

You can either run through all td elements and just skip those that only contain whitespaces (that is what I outlined above using the nested foreach).

In this case it might be better to just pick the first 3 td items directly and add their nodeValue to the array.

```
foreach ($nodes as $trNode)
{
    $tdNodes = $trNode->childNodes;
    $trData = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < $tdNodes->length; $i++) 
    {
        $trData[] = $tdNodes->item($i)->nodeValue;
    }
    $data[] = $trData;
}
```

In the end you have a 2 level $data array containing one array for each table row. The row arrays then contain departure, arrival and connecting trains.

Comment: Thanks but i have Call to undefined method DOMElement::nodeValue()

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault. nodeValue is a **property** not a _method_.

Answer (score 2):

I think here is a typo in your Xpath expression. The width of the table in the HTML is `550`. And you don't need the first two tr elements, so they can be skipped.

```
$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//table[@width="550"]/tr[position() > 2]');
```

You can provide the $node as a context for other xpath expressions. DOMXpath::query() and DOMXpath::evaluate() support that. But only DOMXpath::evaluate() can return scalar values directly.

```
$xpath->evaluate('string(td[1])', $node);
```

The Xpath function `string()` casts the text content of the first node to a string. With DOMXpath:query() this would be:

```
$xpath->query('td[1]', $node)->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Example:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
@$document->loadHtml( $content );
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);
$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('//table[@width="550"]/tr[position() > 2]');
$data = array();
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
  $data[] = array(
    'departure' => $xpath->evaluate('string(td[1])', $node),
    'arrival' => $xpath->evaluate('string(td[2])', $node),
    'info' => $xpath->evaluate('string(td[3])', $node)
  );
}
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: This is actually the more elegant way to solve the problem because it doesn't rely on the bgcolor attribute but simply skips the first rows that act as a legend. (This is more likely to stay that way while changing the background color is not so uncommon)